# ELF64 Reflective Loading

Tags: malware, elf

I'm looking for an ELF64 reflective loader, so I can download an ELF and execute it without saving to disk?

Is anyone able to point me at one please?  Or a clear one for ELF32 so I can translate?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Code for diskless loading of ELF Shared Library using Reflective DLL Injection
https://github.com/nsxz/ReflectiveELFLoader

> Code for diskless loading of ELF Shared Library using Reflective DLL
>   Injection technique. Currently, this is only designed to work on
>   x86_64 (AMD64) architecture on Linux. I was originally hoping to be
>   able to expand this to other architectures and FreeBSD. However, I do
>   not have time to implement this on other architectures and since I
>   only need it to work on x86_64 on Linux this is the only portion I
>   have implemented.

Comment: Hi thanks. I've seen your code already, I'm looking to load a static binary into a process which is already mapped to 0x40000, will it remap the code for whether it gets malloced?

Comment: You should mention that you already see the code in your question, and it's not my code.